# converting single column to equal rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, matrix, plsql

I have a requirement to display one column in a matrix table.

ex:

```
Select SlotNumber from Parking_lot_table;
```

out:

```
SL01
SL02
SL03
SL04
SL05
SL06
SL07
SL08
SL09
SL10
```

My Output must be like :

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 
SL01  SL02  SL03  SL04  SL05
SL06  SL07  SL08  SL09  SL10
```

even Its fine to fix the number of columns ...

Kindly suggest ... How to do this in Oracle SQL

Comment: you could use the [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) functionality

Comment: Please tell us the logic around what determines how a record is placed into one of the five desired output columns.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for the quick reply ....  I will google on this ... if you have any sample kindly share ...

Comment: Hi Tim, There is no logic behind, I have to list the Parking Slots as Images in a Table Structure, so I need to accommodate all slots into a Matrix Structure so that USers could see the current status of slots in a single layout ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
( select  trunc((rownum -1) / 5 ) gr , mod(rownum, 5) rn, slot
   from
  ( select * from 
  parking_lot_table order by to_number(REGEXP_REPLACE(slot, '[^0-9]+', ''))
  )  
  )
  pivot
  (  max(slot) 
   for rn in ( 1  as Col1, 2 as Col2, 3 as Col3, 4 as Col4,  0 as Col5) )
  order by 1
```

Comment: hi dcieslak, the solution seems to suit my requirement exactly, however im working on sorting it as same as what I have posted... thanks a lot for the headsup, that too with a direct query ...

Comment: I added sorting by number that is extracted from slot field.

Comment: Woow... it works Great :) no words to thank you! dcieslak

Happy Coding !